# Maintaining Transactions || Commit & Rollback || ORDS Vs DB Proc Call || Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, transactions

We have two tables named XXTB_PAYMENT_REQUEST and XXTB_PR_DISTRIBUTION. We use a PLSQL Procedure to insert/update data into these tables. This Procedure is exposed as an ORDS service, allowing it to be invoked by other applications as a Rest API.

The problem we are facing is that when the API is executed, if the procedure fails to insert data into the second table (XXTB_PR_DISTRIBUTION), it does not roll back the data that was already inserted into the XXTB_PAYMENT_REQUEST table. However, when I run the procedure locally from my SQL Developer as a procedure call, it works fine and considers the call as one single transaction.

What should be done to ensure that the API also considers the call as one single transaction?

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE xxtb_payment_request (
    pr_number VARCHAR2(5),
    org_name  VARCHAR2(10),
    amount    NUMBER,
    PRIMARY KEY ( pr_number )
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE xxtb_pr_distribution (
    pr_number   VARCHAR2(5)
        CONSTRAINT fk_prnum_distr
            REFERENCES xxtb_payment_request,
    line_number NUMBER,
    cost_center VARCHAR2(5),
    PRIMARY KEY ( pr_number,
                  line_number )
);
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE save_pr (
    p_pr_number_in   IN VARCHAR2,
    p_org_name_in    IN VARCHAR2,
    p_amount_in      IN NUMBER,
    p_cost_center_in IN VARCHAR2,
    p_line_number_in IN NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO xxtb_payment_request xpr
    USING (
        SELECT
            p_pr_number_in AS pr_number_in,
            p_org_name_in  AS org_name_in,
            p_amount_in    AS amount_in
        FROM
            dual
    ) p_params ON ( xpr.pr_number = p_params.pr_number_in )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET xpr.org_name = p_params.org_name_in,
        xpr.amount = p_params.amount_in
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
        pr_number,
        org_name,
        amount )
    VALUES
        ( p_params.pr_number_in,
          p_params.org_name_in,
          p_params.amount_in );

    MERGE INTO xxtb_pr_distribution xpd
    USING (
        SELECT
            p_pr_number_in   AS pr_number_in,
            p_line_number_in AS line_number_in,
            p_cost_center_in AS cost_center_in
        FROM
            dual
    ) d_params ON ( xpd.pr_number = d_params.pr_number_in
                    AND xpd.line_number = d_params.line_number_in )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET xpd.cost_center = d_params.cost_center_in
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
        pr_number,
        line_number,
        cost_center )
    VALUES
        ( d_params.pr_number_in,
          d_params.line_number_in,
          d_params.cost_center_in );

    COMMIT;
END save_pr;
```

Test Script:

Successfully inserts the data into both tables:

```
BEGIN
    save_pr(p_pr_number_in => 'PR102', 
            p_org_name_in => 'ORG102', 
            p_amount_in => 1000, 
            p_cost_center_in => 'CC102', 
            p_line_number_in => 1
    );
END;
```

This call encounters an error and fails to insert data into both tables due to the Cost Center value exceeding the maximum allowed length.

```
BEGIN
    save_pr(p_pr_number_in => 'PR103', 
            p_org_name_in => 'ORG103', 
            p_amount_in => 1000, 
            p_cost_center_in => 'CC1033', 
            p_line_number_in => 1
    );
END;
```

ORDS Setup:

```
BEGIN
ORDS.ENABLE_SCHEMA(
      p_enabled             => TRUE,
      p_schema              => 'DB_USER',
      p_url_mapping_type    => 'BASE_PATH',
      p_url_mapping_pattern => 'db_user',
      p_auto_rest_auth      => FALSE);    

ORDS.DEFINE_MODULE(
      p_module_name    => 'test_payment_request',
      p_base_path      => '/prtest/',
      p_items_per_page =>  25,
      p_status         => 'PUBLISHED',
      p_comments       => NULL);    
      
ORDS.DEFINE_TEMPLATE(
      p_module_name    => 'test_payment_request',
      p_pattern        => 'savePayReq',
      p_priority       => 0,
      p_etag_type      => 'HASH',
      p_etag_query     => NULL,
      p_comments       => NULL);
ORDS.DEFINE_HANDLER(
      p_module_name    => 'test_payment_request',
      p_pattern        => 'savePayReq',
      p_method         => 'POST',
      p_source_type    => 'plsql/block',
      p_items_per_page =>  0,
      p_mimes_allowed  => 'application/json',
      p_comments       => NULL,
      p_source         => 
'begin

save_pr(    p_pr_number_in => :pr_number_in, 
            p_org_name_in => :org_name_in, 
            p_amount_in => :amount_in, 
            p_cost_center_in => :cost_center_in, 
            p_line_number_in => :line_number_in
    );      

:return_status := ''SUCCESS'';
:return_message := ''Saved successfully.'';

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        :status := 400;
        :return_status := ''ERROR'';
        :return_message := ''System response: '' || sqlerrm;

end;'
      
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your REST service must be concluding its session with an auto-commit, where your other client doesn't do so.

Your code doesn't have an exception handler, so if your second SQL fails, there is nothing to rollback the first SQL except the client itself, outside the procedure. Some clients may be configured for auto-commit, others not. Therein is your difference. It is not safe to let stateless APIs like REST calls and Web-based calls create transactions that are left open by your procedures. Always ensure you do an explicit commit or rollback before returning control, and that includes in error conditions.

So, if you want a failure in the second SQL to always rollback the first SQL, you need to program that into the procedure itself. Look at the very end:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE save_pr (
    p_pr_number_in   IN VARCHAR2,
    p_org_name_in    IN VARCHAR2,
    p_amount_in      IN NUMBER,
    p_cost_center_in IN VARCHAR2,
    p_line_number_in IN NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO xxtb_payment_request xpr
    USING (
        SELECT
            p_pr_number_in AS pr_number_in,
            p_org_name_in  AS org_name_in,
            p_amount_in    AS amount_in
        FROM
            dual
    ) p_params ON ( xpr.pr_number = p_params.pr_number_in )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET xpr.org_name = p_params.org_name_in,
        xpr.amount = p_params.amount_in
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
        pr_number,
        org_name,
        amount )
    VALUES
        ( p_params.pr_number_in,
          p_params.org_name_in,
          p_params.amount_in );

    MERGE INTO xxtb_pr_distribution xpd
    USING (
        SELECT
            p_pr_number_in   AS pr_number_in,
            p_line_number_in AS line_number_in,
            p_cost_center_in AS cost_center_in
        FROM
            dual
    ) d_params ON ( xpd.pr_number = d_params.pr_number_in
                    AND xpd.line_number = d_params.line_number_in )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET xpd.cost_center = d_params.cost_center_in
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
        pr_number,
        line_number,
        cost_center )
    VALUES
        ( d_params.pr_number_in,
          d_params.line_number_in,
          d_params.cost_center_in );

    COMMIT;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ROLLBACK;
      RAISE;
END save_pr;
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, @Paul W. The issue is resolved, and everything is functioning correctly now. I'll make sure to implement this solution while writing other procedures.